# Download CSV file header is gets junk when Japanese language selected in Linux server in Java

Tags: java, linux, encoding

[image]When we download CSV file from Linux server using java code header value is gets junk for Japanese language. 
It is working fine when run on window platform. 
Following is my sample code.

```
File file = File.createTempFile("temp", null);
String fileName = "Temp";
HttpServletResponse response;
CsvConfig config = new CsvConfig(',', '"', '\\');
config.setBreakString(config.getBreakString());
Csv.save(getApplicationData, file, CSVUtil.getDefaultConfig(),
        new ColumnNameMappingBeanListHandler<WDTO>(WDTO.class)
               .column(label 1, "Date")
               .column(label 2, "Name")
               .column(label 3, "description")
               .column(label 4, "appName")
               .column(label 5, "status"));
DownloadUtils.download(file, fileName, response);
```

Here, label 1, label 2 etc are in two language(English,Japanese). When we select English then working fine in both environment(Linux,Window). 
But when we select Japanese it is working fine in window only, not working in Linux.

Attached image is showing how data gets junk.

My output is showing like this.

逕ｳ隲区律   繝輔か繝ｼ繝 隱ｬ譏・逕ｳ隲玖・繧ｹ繝・・繧ｿ繧ｹ
2018/11/13  譌･蝣ｱ    譌･蝣ｱ    VJM 逕ｳ隲倶ｸｭ

What is wrong in the code or is there any other way solve this issue.

Comment: Make sure your linux os has Japanese language support

Comment: so what are these classes you are using?

Comment: minimum viable test case needed: file that breaks, resulting output, preferably desired output. Default encoding in linux and windows are different so maybe that's the problem, but unless you want us to play prophets, add something for us to work with

Comment: Linux server has Japanese language support and both server running on same encoding. Still facing this issue.

Comment: I added sample code that I am using for download CSV. Let me know which other information you need @Sarief

Comment: @VJM if I run that code on CSV I create it will be ok for me and I won't have error you have. Include CSV that fails, and encoding you use. You don't have to include full csv, only part that breaks

Comment: @Sarief thanks for reply I update my question with output file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this issue resolved. I've changed my code below and the title value is not junk for Japanese.

```
File file = File.createTempFile("temp", null);
String fileName = "Temp";
HttpServletResponse response;
CsvConfig config = new CsvConfig(',', '"', '\\');
config.setBreakString(config.getBreakString());
final OutputStreamWriter out = new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(file), "Shift_JIS");
Csv.save(getApplicationData, out , CSVUtil.getDefaultConfig(),
    new ColumnNameMappingBeanListHandler<WDTO>(WDTO.class)
           .column(label 1, "Date")
           .column(label 2, "Name")
           .column(label 3, "description")
           .column(label 4, "appName")
           .column(label 5, "status"));
DownloadUtils.download(file, fileName, response);
```